# How do I snatch the error code from the trap frame?

Tags: windows, exception, kernel, windbg

[The Tao of Programming](http://www.talisman.org/tao/) begins with the words:

> Thus spake the master programmer:
>
> "When you have learned to snatch the error code from the trap frame,
>   it will be time for you to leave."

Please enlighten me.

Comment: I think he's talking about the girls.

Comment: Looks like some info at the following link - but I don't use windows much these days, and it's a bit 'low level' for me to understand: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/24/9013856.aspx

Comment: Are you sure the Master was referring to Windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not for the master to enlighten the novice, it is for the novice to travel the pathways to become a master.  When you see Tao you know.